# What is the API for basic tier VM in azure?

Tags: azure

Microsoft announced and released via their website, a new tier of VM called "Basic" that are cheaper than the normal one. We can make it basic through the portal, however, what is the REST API to do it programmatically ?

I see no way of doing it either in powershell or code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used PowerShell Cmdlets so I wouldn't know how that would work there. But if you're using [`REST API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157194.aspx), to create a Virtual Machine under basic tier, you just have to prefix the role size with **`Basic_`**.

So if you're creating a **`Medium Size Virtual Machine (A2)`**, you have to specify role size as **`Basic_A2`** and that should do the trick. <del>Also, please make sure that the Service Management API version is set as **`2014-04-01`**</del>.

Comment: and it works, and it does not seems I need to use version 2014 ! :)